# Is there a way to reload an angular.js directive outside of the ui-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on an app that has a component outside the ui-view (navigation bar). This component includes a directive that should add a listener to some async event that happens after $location changes. I have the same directive in numerous places within the ui-view. The problem is that while the directives within the ui-view are re-rendered with every $location change, the directive within the navigation bar doesn't re-render and the listener isn't assigned. 
Any idea how to force directive re-rendering?

Index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
   <nav class="cf" ng-include="'app/components/registration/nav.html'"></nav>
   <div ui-view autoscroll="true"></div>
</body>
```

nav.html:

```
<div ng-controller="RegistrationController">
    <my-directive></my-directive> 
</div>
```

directive.js:

```
function myDirective(WSService, ShoutingRoomService, VIDABOO_CONSTANTS, $rootScope, $scope) {
return {
    scope: {},
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    bindToController: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $rootScope.$on('SomeAsyncEvent', function(event, data) {
            WSService.doWhenSomeAsyncEventHappens(function () {
                 changeSomethingVisibleInHTMLTemplate(); 
            }) ;
        });
     },
     template: '<div>ChangeThisWhenAsyncEventHappens</div>'
    };
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to force Angular to relink `$scope` and your template together?

Quick summary of $compile:

> The compilation is a process of walking the DOM tree and matching DOM
>   elements to directives.

That would be my suggestion. Try adding something like this to your code:

```
$compile(angular.element('div.someElement').contents())($scope);
```

Comment: can we move to chat? need to ask you something